# Will a module created for OXID 6.0 be backward compatible with a lower version?

Tags: oxid

Will a module created for OXID 6.0 be backward compatible with lower versions (i.e.: OXID 5.0) in terms of installation and activation?

Answer (score 2):

If the new metadata version 2.0 and namespaces are used the module will not be backwards compatible. Modules for version 4/5 did not use namespaces and installation was done by file copy, the new recommended way is to use namespaces and install the module with composer.

Also the database layer has changed in Version 6, if the module has interactions with the database the corresponding code slightly differs from version 4/5 (using AdoDB) to version 6 (using doctrine).

So it might be possible that a module created for OXID 4/5 will work in version 6, but in most cases you will need separate versions of the module.

More information can be found here: https://docs.oxid-esales.com/developer/en/6.0/

Answer (score 0):

No, this will never work this way. OXID6 provides only temporary backward compatibility for older modules. I think they will stop supporting older modules when all oxid-esales modules will be rewritten to new oxid6 format.